# Problem with django urls which have a hyphen in them

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I have a simple set of urls in a Django url conf file which points to some object detail generic views.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',  
url(r'^projects/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='view_project'),
url(r'^roles/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', RoleDetailView.as_view(), name='view_role'),
)
```

The problem is whenever there's a hyphen in the urls (eg:-`/projects/new-project/`) slug, Djangos development server get stuck. I've checked with pdb and there isn't a problem with parsing the url and getting the object from the database based on the slug. But it gets stuck somewhere when the template gets rendered. I can't figure out the source of the problem. any idea what the problem is?

The view code is,

```
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
  model=Project
  context_object_name='project_obj'
  slug_field='slug'

  @method_decorator(login_required)
  def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ProjectDetailView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The template code is,

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% get_static_prefix %}css/demo_table.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{% get_static_prefix %}js/users-index.js"></script>
    {% endblock %}

        {% block content %}
        <div id="itemlist">    

          {% if project_obj %}
          <div>
            <p>{{ project_obj.title }}</p>
            <p>{{ project_obj.description }}</p>
          </div>
          {% else %}
          <p>No Details available.</p>
          {% endif %}
        <div>
        {% endblock %}
```

After removing some of the tags from the template it started working,

```
<div id="itemlist">    

      {% if project_obj %}
      <div>
        <p>{{ project_obj.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ project_obj.description }}</p>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <p>No Details available.</p>
      {% endif %}
    <div>
```

Comment: If the problem isn't in the URLs, why are you pasting the URLs? Please include the offending template and view code.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've included them now

Comment: Your code looks fine, I suggest cutting pieces out until it works, then slowly re-add them to identify exactly what's breaking it. If you get that far and can't figure it out, post what you identified as the cause :)

Comment: I thought someone might have experienced this before. It really is a strange problem because the server doesn't get stuck for other urls which doesn't have a hyphen in them. The problem seem to start in [loader_tags.py](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/loader_tags.py) when stepped through with pdb.

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug without a traceback. Like I said, keep cutting down/simplifying your template until it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, It starts working when I remove all `extends` tags and `block` tags. Have any idea what the problem could be? remainder is included in the question.

Comment: Add the `extends` tag, check if it works, then add an empty `block` tag, then check if it works, then add some content to the `block` tag, etc etc etc.

Comment: after adding `extends` tag it stops working.

Comment: Leave `extends` in, now start cutting down `base.html` until it works.

Comment: One of the custom template tags i wrote had caused the problem. Thanks for helping me find the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you wrote a custom template tag, but it's broken. You're using it in `base.html` :P

Comment: yes, I had a custom template tag in base.html to process breadcrumbs. It was having trouble parsing the url with hyphens.

Answer (score 5):

Change `[\w-]+` to `[-\w]+`. For me `[\w-]+` never works with python regexp's.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work either. I believe it's not a regex issue, Because with python debugger I could see object being retrieved from the database using the slug.